# Grails on AppFog: BIRT report displayed partially

Tags: grails, birt, appfog

Within my Grails 2.2 application I use BIRT reporting plugin to generate a pdf of (a bit) complex report (7 datasets binded to 8th one) and it works ok on my local machine but, on AppFog, I get only aprox 1/3 of report. The problem is that I get Header and footer of document but, content is broken at different places at different attempt so It looks like some kind of time-out problem, like report engine hadn't had enough time to generate itself.
Do I forget to set something or? Anybody have a idea what to try?

Comment: Are you using the report engine api?  Did you set a query timeout in the property binding for the dataset?

Comment: Hi Jason.I'm using BIRT plugin for Grails (http://grails.org/plugin/birt-report) with somehow limited number of options to set. On other side, on report, I didn't set anything specific neither I can see that timeout is set. Anyhow, I will try to check for possibilities of timeout settings. Thx